# How can i change my C code?

Tags: c

I'm beginner in C programming and i have a problem with my code . I wanted to write a C code that when i give a reverse sentence to it , the program print that sentence in usual arranged . ( You can see the example ) . my problem is when i don't put any sign like ? or ! etc , the sentence hasn't printed correctly . ( See the example )
Can you help me to solve this problem ? I want a code to show arranged all kind of reverse sentence that i give to it . ( Excuse me for my English)

```
Example :
Input :  oD uoy tnaw ot eunitnoc?
Output:  Do you want to continue?
```

but when i write this sentence whithout ? sign :

```
Input :  oD uoy tnaw ot eunitnoc
Output:  Do you want to
```

and it doesn't show 'continue'

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    int ch, i, j, k;

    for (i=0; i<sizeof(sentence)-1; i++)
    if ((sentence[i] = getchar()) == '\n')
    break;

    sentence[i] = '\0';

    for (j = 0; j <i; j++)
    {
        if(islower(sentence[j])||isupper(sentence[j]))
        continue;
        for( k=j-1;sentence[k]!=' ' && k>=0;k--)
        {
            ch=sentence[k];
            putchar(ch);
        }
        ch=sentence[j];
        putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried a lot of logical ways but the result wasn't change :( .

Comment: I think we have a new school class here on SO! This question with the exact same input and program was asked like 2 or 3 times before :D

Comment: `if(islower(sentence[j])||isupper(sentence[j]))` - So, if the letter is lower *or* upper case, you don't copy the remaining characters?  Think about that and then think about your problem with punctuation.

Comment: @EdS.: I believe that the code there is advancing `j` to the first non-alpha character. Word parsing I believe.

Comment: @EdS. the long way of writing `if (!isalpha(sentence[j]))` apparently.

Comment: @BillLynch: Right, but he said that, if he leaves punctuation out, he skips a word

Comment: You really, __really__ need to use better variable names so that people can follow what you are trying to do. What is `i`, `j`, and `k`? Aren't there more meaningful names you could apply to those variables?

Comment: Can only agree with @BillLynch it's very important to have good/ meaningful variable names!

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
for (j = 0; j <i; j++)
```

to this

```
for (j = 0; j <=i; j++)
```

Comment: I have change it before writing this question but when i do this the answer of first example will turn to Do you want to continue??continue

Answer (score 0):

2nd for-loop change to

```
for (j = 0; j <=i; j++)
{
    if(isalpha(sentence[j]))
        continue;
    for( k=j-1; k>=0 && isalpha(sentence[k]);k--)
    {
        putchar(sentence[k]);
    }
    if(sentence[j])
        putchar(sentence[j]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer's in `C` tags are every time the best :D Maybe you could explain to OP what's going on/ what you have changed so that it works now.

Comment: 1) `k>=0` : You need check first. 2) `sentence[k]!=' '` : Error to compare space(`' '`) only. Discrepancy occurs on the meaning. 3) `if(sentence[j])` : Check '\0' so were included in the scanning range.